# how to remove the trailing word after a specific pattern is found using awk/sed unix command?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

i am trying to remove the trailing word from a specific pattern found.
the example shown below:

```
file.txt
a/b/c/d/susan[123]
a/b/c/d/susan[456]
a/b/c/d/susan[890]
s/t/u/v/adam[12]
s/t/u/v/adam[50]
```

i would like the result of the file to be:

```
a/b/c/d/susan
s/t/u/v/adam
```

how could i use awk/sed command to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: i would like to remove the duplicates too. thanks mklement0

Comment: actually, i have example 100 signal in different bits, but out of this 100 signals they could be split into a few groups,

Comment: Please update your answer directly to clarify the duplicate-removal requirement, and also add a note that you clarified later, so as not to invalidate existing answers. Regarding the grouping by bits: I suggest you ask a _new_ question, and provide sufficient detail. In the future, please try to state all your requirements up front.

Answer (score 3):

In a simple scenario such as this, `cut` is all you need:

```
cut -d '[' -f1 file.txt
```

This simply returns the substring before the first occurrence of `[` on each line.

---

In case your sample output's omission of duplicates is not just an accident: if your input records are grouped like that and you want to weed out duplicates, simply pipe to `uniq`:

```
cut -d '[' -f1 file.txt | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with sed:

```
sed 's/\(.[^[]*\).*/\1/g' file.txt
```

This uses sed grouping and back referencing. The `\(...\)` captures anything from the beginning of the line up to `[` (excluding it: `.[^[]*`). It then matches the remaining characters, ie. `[...]`. The first group delimited by `\(...\)` can be then back-referenced with `\1`.

Basically I group what I want to keep and reference it in the substitution part of the sed command `\1` (meaning group number 1).

Comment: How about adding a quick explanation how this works? This answer was automatically flagged as "low quality", which it isn't really - but code-only answers tend to get flagged.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: I suggest anchoring the regex at the start of the string (for clarity of intent) and removing the unnecessary `g`: `sed 's/^\(.[^[]*\).*/\1/' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

mklement0's answer is probably the best, but if you want to do it with awk or sed.

`awk`: `awk -F'[' '{print $1}' file.txt`

`sed`: `sed 's/\[[0-9]*\]$//' file.txt`

Comment: ++; both commands work well with the sample input data, but it's worth noting that the `sed` command not only uses a _complementary_ approach to the `awk` command - it _removes_ everything starting with the first `[`, but is also more restrictive, by only matching (zero or more) _digits_ after the `[`, and requiring a closing `]`.

Comment: Thanks for the additions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use grep to extract the part before the opening bracket, and then pipe the results to uniq:

```
grep -Eo '^[^[]+' file | uniq
```

I assume that `file` is sorted, because you shown that in your demo data. If that is not the case you need to sort the output before passing it to uniq:

```
grep -Eo '^[^[]+' file | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

One proposal to remove duplicates as well.

```
awk -F'[[]' '/12/{print $1}' file
a/b/c/d/susan
s/t/u/v/adam
```

Comment: Honestly, basing the detection of duplicates on whether they contain literal `12` is a terrible idea - unless all the input you'll ever have to deal with happens to be the sample data in the question.